# Connect two wireless routers with LAN cable over a distance of 100 meters

Tags: ethernet, lan, bridge

I have a fiber optic coaxial connection in my home connected to a wireless router provided by my ISP.

My office is not far away from my house but I don't receive a wireless signal from the router so I have set up a CAT6 Ethernet cable from the LAN port of primary router to my office which is nearly 80 metres away.

When I hook up the cable directly to my laptop it works well, but can anyone now guide me on how to set up a wireless router in my office from the LAN cable? I have an extra TP-Link router and I tried bridging the TP-Link router with the one provided by my ISP but it doesn't work since the wireless signal from the primary router does not reach my office.

The IP address of primary router is `192.168.0.1` and TP-Link is `192.168.1.1` with same `255.255.255.0` subnet for both.

Comment: Disable DHCP on the tp-link -> set it to have a manual IP just outside your primary router DHCP -> plug the ethernet into one of the LAN ports of your tp-link -> configure the tp-link wireless to be identical to the primary (ssid, encryption, passphrase, channel) -> done.

Comment: Don't worry about the primary wireless as the tp-link wireless will be used in your office and the primary wireless when your laptop/phone is at home. This diagram is what you're achieving: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-aDdGUezN1CA/TzaZGKFVNbI/AAAAAAAAAh8/dYDrOspkfc8/s1600/Final%2Bdiagram.png

Comment: I'm unsure about your question title "over 100m" as you then say the distance is 80m...

Comment: Do what @BigChris said -- change the IP address of the new router to something like `192.168.0.2` or `192.168.0.254`. Don't use its WAN port for any purpose -- the new router is not connected to the WAN and doesn't need to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers...sorry 4 confusing about the distance...I will explain step by step since English is not my first language.

Comment: Ok. So I set my router with an ip of 192.168.0.2 then disabled the dhcp. Connected the CaT 6 to the lan port but none of my devices can connect to the router. Is it because my primary router is out of range?

Comment: It'll be because you set the tp-link to have an IP within the primary DHCP range. You'll need to log in to your primary router and see what its DHCP pool is configured with. You may find it offers IPs in the range 192.168.0.2 to about .0.100 or higher. You will need to investigate...

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect these two router through the LAN ports.
And disable the DHCP server on Home router.
http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-417.html

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is try a bridging mode. Then you have a single `168.192.0.0/24` network. Use an high address for the bridge (168.192.0.250 or more) to avoid conflict with addresses given by the router. (168.192.0.2 is likely to be given to something else). DHCP should be disabled too.

If you can’t use a bridging, the `168.192.1.0/24` network on WLAN is welcome, but you should put a 168.192.0.250 address (or something like this) on the LAN side and activates NAT (network address translation). DHCP should be enabled on `182.168.1.0/24` only